# how do I get the cache memory and Main memory using block size?

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I'm learning the concept of directed mapped cache, but I don't get it how to get cache memory size and main memory size by using block size. (The unit is bytes.) the given values are 2^3 words = 2^5 bytes of block size, 4 bits of tags(0000~1111) and 3 bits of the index(000~111).

the questions >>

1. what's the size of cache memory and main memory in each?
2. and which address do we insert in each data part?

[image]

I already tried to separate the part tag and the cache index. I insert the tag on 3 upper order bits and insert the cache index(29 bits) on the remaining space. I got the main memory size, 4GB, and the cache size, 2^29 bytes. but I think something is wrong. I feel that I don't understand the concept of this.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is incorrect, because you are assuming address is 32 bits and it is byte addressable, hence the 4GB memory size. This is not true and we must first compute these values.

8 words = 32 bytes = block size
So offset=3 bits (to address 8 words in a block)
and word size=4 bytes/word (32 bytes/8 words)

We have now the width of an address: 4 bits (tag) + 3 bits (index) +  3 bits (offset)= 10 bits.

With 10 bits address, main memory is 2^10 words=2^12 bytes=4kB

Cache has 8 blocks (3 bits index), each block has 32 bytes and cache size=8*32 bytes=256B.